# Vue update v-for property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I am rendering a list from a beers array like this:

```
<tr v-for="beer in beers">
    <td class="switch">
        <input v-model="beer.verified" v-on:click="verify">
        <label for="cmn-toggle-{{$index}}"></label>
    </td>
<tr>
```

When I click on one of the beer inputs from the list that was rendered from my array of beers I want to update the verified property of that specific beer on my beers objects.

I checked the event but I am not sure how to handle this with Vue.

```
methods: {
    verify: function(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
},
```

Can somebody guide me in the right direction or workflow so I can easily update the specific beer property that was clicked on.

**Edit**

Nevermind. It was as simply as passing the current beer through to the verify method like so:

```
v-on:click="verify(beer)"
```

This allowed me to manipulate the current items properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `beer` to the click handling function. By default, it receives the Event object, but very often you don't need that. Instead, you want to deal with your data.

[The documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Inline-Statement-Handler) gives examples of passing constants, but model variables are fair game (and more likely what you'll use). The example below increments the `verified` value on each click.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    beers: [{
      verified: 0
    }, {
      verified: 0
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    verify: function(beer) {
      ++beer.verified;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr v-for="beer in beers">
    <td class="switch">
      <input v-model="beer.verified" v-on:click="verify(beer)">
      <label for="cmn-toggle-{{$index}}"></label>
    </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```